# How do I get the Name and Address on the Invoice to show up in a Window Envelope?

Tags: message-templates, invoice

A client recently asked me the following question: I need to be able to mail (postal mail) invoices to our Members. Our pre-printed size 10 envelopes have a window bottom-left. How can I get the Member's Name and Address on the Invoice to show up in that Window?

Answer (score 4):

This requires editing of the Contribution Invoice Receipt - Message Template. End result looks like this:

I'll detail the steps below to get the header part.

[image]

The header portion contains two tables: the first table is used to add your logo. The second table has the formatting for the Name and Address section: note that we're putting the Member's Name and Address on the far left and in a slight larger font.

```
   <table width="100%" border = "0" style = "margin-top:20px;margin-right:40px;">
        <tr>
          <td align="right" height="50"><img src = "https://www.yoursite.com/sites/yoursite/files/logo_250x.png"></td>
        </tr>
   </table>

   <table width="100%" border = "0" cellpadding = "2" cellspacing = "1" style = "margin-top:35px;margin-right:20px; font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;">
        <tr>
          <td width="40%" rowspan="3"><b><font size = "4" align = "center">{ts}INVOICE{/ts}</font></b></td>
          <td width="25%"><b><font size = "1" >{ts}Invoice Date{/ts}</font></b><font size = "2"> </font></td>
          <td width="35%"><font size = "1">{$domain_organization}</font></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td><font size = "1">{$invoice_date}</font><font size = "2"> </font></td>
          <td><font size = "1">{$domain_street_address}</font></td>
        </tr>

       <tr>
          <td><font size = "1"></font><font size = "2"> </font></td>
          <td><font size = "1">{if $domain_city}{$domain_city|upper}{/if} {if $domain_state }{$domain_state}{/if} {$domain_postal_code}</font></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td><font size = "2">{$display_name}</font></td>
          <td><b><font size = "1" align = "right">{ts}Invoice Number{/ts}</font></b></td>
          <td><font size = "1">{if $domain_country}{$domain_country|upper}{/if}</font></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td><font size = "2">{$street_address} {$supplemental_address_1}</font></td>
          <td><font size = "1">{$invoice_number}</font></td>
          <td><font size = "1">{if $domain_email}{$domain_email}{/if}</font></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td><font size = "2">{$city|upper} {$stateProvinceAbbreviation} {$postal_code}</font></td>
          <td></td>
          <td><font size = "1"> {if $domain_phone}{$domain_phone}{/if}</font> </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td><b><font size = "1">{ts}Reference{/ts}</font></b><font size = "2"> </font></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>

       <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td><font size = "1">{$source}</font><font size = "2"> </font></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
```